# Why should always a:hover come after a:link and a:visited?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm learning CSS. I'm getting confused when I faced up the order '`:hover` must come after `:link` and `:visited`'.

Practically, in order to visit a link, we have to click it first and in order to click the link, we need to hover it. If so, why such constraints in order..??
Kindly help.

Comment: because `a:hover` has exactly the same specificity as `a:link`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given CSS selectors that are equally specific, rules are applied in order.

If an anchor is both a link and hovered, then both rules will apply.

```
a:hover { color: blue; }
a:link { color: red; }
```

It is hovered so it is blue, but it is a link, so the blue is overwritten with red.

That makes the hover rule more-or-less pointless.